# How to configure community server to make contact us page work?

Tags: asp.net, web

I have a community server website, i have contact us page enabled in it, but for a reason i don't know its not working.
But all notifications i receive on the same mail when some one send a comment on a post or forum.

Any one can tell me whats the problem or how i can solve or configure?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try posting your problem on the Community Server support site.

http://dev.communityserver.com/forums/

Yours is not a programming question and doesn't really belong on stackoverflow.

Comment: You are right, i must sent there on their forums, thanks for advice.
But one note: i think community server is programming related subject.